# Fill form via chrome extension popup

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, browser-action

I want to load values from **fill.js** and when the anchor link in extension **popup.html** is clicked it will autofill form fields on a remote page that has field IDs of **#user** + **#pw**. This is what i currently have in my extension but i'm not sure if it's missing something in the manifest file or if **back.js** is needed.

**fill.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
if (msg.action === "fillFields") {
    $("#user").val("name@email.com")
    $("#pw").val("pass123")
}
});
```

**popup.js**

```
$("#fill").on("click", function(){
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: 'fillFields'
});
```

});

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Autofill</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<a href="#" id="fill">Fill</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Autofill",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
       "default_title": "Autofill",
       "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"    
    ]
  }
```

**Remote form fields**

```
<input name="user" type="text" id="user">
<input name="pw" type="text" id="pw">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the #fill element from your fill.js, which is injected into the page (i.e. a content script). The popup runs in one scope, the content in another and background in another.

Injecting the jquery and fill scripts as you're doing on the browser action is better than loading it in the manifest because it'll only inject when needed and the handler will be ready by the time you click fill in the popup.

Add this to popup.html:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

popup.js:

```
$("#fill").on("click", function(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        action: 'fillFields'
    });
});
```

fill.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.action === "fillFields") {
        $("#user").val("name@email.com")
        $("#pw").val("pass123")
    }
});
```

Lookup run_at to have control over when scripts are injected. You should have no problem as there's a natural delay between browser action click and being able to click fill.

Comment: Thanks! but i am looking to be able to click a fill link from the popup menu (as i may have more than one set of values and multiple links) Is that possible?

Comment: The fill link is on the popup in my answer

Comment: to use multiple fill links, just send and respond to additional messages, e.g. fillFields2

Comment: It doesnt show html anchor link  <a href="#fill">Fill</a>  when i click the extension icon

Comment: The instruction was **Add** this to popup.html:

Comment: That's what i have done but the popup doesn't show when i click the icon. Do i have to change 'content_scripts' to something else?

Comment: you've got popup.html defined in the popup section of the manifest, right. All that should be the same as the original so the popup should show when you click on the extension browser button. It did when you first posted the question and what I told you to do shouldn't have changed that.

Comment: i.e. you still have "browser_action": {
            "default_icon": "icon.png",
             "default_title": "fill",
             "default_popup": "popup.html"
          }, in the manifest

Comment: Sorry yes. What i meant was that when i click the link in popout it doesn't do anything. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159274/discussion-between-troy-wray-and-7o07y7).